# Adding local directory as gradle dependency

Tags: java, gradle

I've seen gradle compile remote repos and local jars, but not directories.

Is this possible? If so, what's the syntax for compiling a directory?

I have jbox2d as a directory (I needed to make some changes to source files), but I'm trying to figure how to add it in gradle.

I can add it manually in my IDE, but I'd much rather have it done by gradle.

Thank you, Tar for your suggestion. 
I've modified my build.gradle to contain:

`dependencies {
    compile 'junit:junit:4.+'
    compile 'com.esotericsoftware:kryonet:2.+'
    compile 'org.slick2d:slick2d-core:1.0.+'
    compile project ':JBox2D'
    compile 'org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl:2.+'
    compile 'org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl_util:2.9.+'
}`

Gradle complains that it can't find JBox2D:

`Could not find property ':JBox2D' on DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='root project 'pong-the-moba'', configuration='default'}.`

I made JBox2D a module and it's living right under root:

`project/
    jbox2d/
    src/
    build.gradle`

Comment: Isn't it problem with casing? Have You added `jbox2d` to `setting.gradle`?

Comment: You're right. Though, I did add it to settings.gradle. I just didnt' have a proper gradle file in jBox2d itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding your modified jbox2d as a module then using Gradle to build it by referring to the module?

```
compile project(':CustomJbox2d')
```

For instance, my Android project builds with Gradle, and I have a facebook library that is built with this section of my `build.gradle` in teh module that depends on it.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}
```

My file structure is something like this:

```
project/
    libraries/
        facebook/
            build.gradle
    my_module/
        build.gradle (this is the one I took the above Gradle code from)
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

Comment: Would I be adding that line under dependencies as well?